# Excel formula to Count zeros only from Left to Right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am currently using the following formula **(i.e.  =IF(A9<>"0";COUNTIF(A9:L9;"0");" "))** in a range "Jan to Dec" to get the number of zeros from left to right only and it is giving me 3 for 1st row, second & third rows as well.  But what I want is, it should count zeros only from left to right (only in first and third cases).  Only in second case it should not count zeros, because they are coming after some value, but it should count in 1st case and 3rd cases.

Can someone please help me with the formula?

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul
0   0   0   5   10  15  20
10  15  20  25  0   0   0
50  0   0   0   30  35  40
```

Comment: 1st Case (Jan = 0; Feb=0; Mar=0; Apr=5; May=10; Jun=15;)

Comment: 2nd Case (Jan = 15; Feb=20; Mar=25; Apr=0; May=0; Jun=0;)

Comment: give us a proper column / row references, or a screenshot of the structure of data + the results column

Comment: Hi, I have saved a sample file in the following link https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0d2a552j8kxtek/Book2.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Results should come in separate column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comment conversation with OP vbalearner, assuming your data setup and desired results look something like this:

[image: tigeravatar example for vbalearner]

Then the formula in the cell and copied down is:

```
=IF(A9=0,IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A9:L9>0,),0)-1,12),IF(B9=0,IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B9:L9>0,),0)-1,12),0))
```

Shortened version:

```
=IF(OR(A9=0,B9=0),IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(IF(A9=0,A9:L9,B9:L9)>0,),0)-1,12),0)
```

Comment: I just checked this formula and it is working only when A9=0, there are cases where A9 is having some value and B9 or C9 is 0, then this formula is not working.  It should work even in this case.

Comment: Sorry.  This was my mistake.  I could have told you in the beginning

Comment: Your question and description both make it sound like you only want to count zeroes starting from the left. In your provided example, the second line should be 0 because the zeroes start at April.  If this is not the case, can you please clarify in detail when you need a count and what should be counted?

Comment: Really sorry for confusing.  I have come across 3rd case where first month we will have value and next few months we will have 0 and again we will have value.  In this case formula should calculate

Comment: Jan=50; Feb=0; Mar=0; Apr=0; May=30; Jun=35; Jul=40

Answer (score 0):

With a helper row inserted at the top (may be hidden) with month numbers (`1` for Jan etc) and assuming `Jan` is then in A2 please try:

```
=MIN(IF(A3:G3<>0;A$1:G$1))-1
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and copied down to suit.